# Hibernate does not close my database query sessions, why?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Comento un poco cómo está hecha mi aplicación: SpringBoot + Hibernate + Multitenant (DB master + DB for tenant) + Postgressql. I have two datasource configurations, one for the master and one for each client's database. To access the apis, A user logs in by obtaining an access token, which contains information from the tenant. Today the project is in an initial stage, we are very few people accessing the database (approx 3).
My

```
show max_connections;
```

In both databases it is 100

But I often skipped this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already.
```

And do :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity;
```

It really is 99,  and pgadmin in service show

[postgres - dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We5DO.png)

**but I don't understand why?**

I leave the configuration code of the datasource

**MASTER**

```
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {

/**
 * Master database configuration properties like username, password, etc.
 */
@Autowired
private MasterDatabaseConfigProperties masterDbProperties;

/**
 * Creates the master datasource bean which is required for creating the entity
 * manager factory bean <br/>
 * <br/>
 * Note that using names for beans is not mandatory but it is a good practice to
 * ensure that the intended beans are being used where required.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
public DataSource masterDataSource() {

    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();

    ds.setUsername(masterDbProperties.getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(masterDbProperties.getPassword());
    ds.setJdbcUrl(masterDbProperties.getUrl());
    ds.setDriverClassName(masterDbProperties.getDriverClassName());
    ds.setPoolName(masterDbProperties.getPoolName());

    // HikariCP settings
    // Maximum number of actual connection in the pool
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(masterDbProperties.getMaxPoolSize());

    // Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
    ds.setMinimumIdle(masterDbProperties.getMinIdle());

    // Maximum waiting time for a connection from the pool
    ds.setConnectionTimeout(masterDbProperties.getConnectionTimeout());

    // Maximum time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool
    ds.setIdleTimeout(masterDbProperties.getIdleTimeout());

    ds.addDataSourceProperty("test-on-borrow", true);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("remove-abandoned", true);
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    // LOG.info("Setup of masterDataSource succeeded.");
    return ds;
}

/**
 * Creates the entity manager factory bean which is required to access the JPA
 * functionalities provided by the JPA persistence provider, i.e. Hibernate in
 * this case. <br/>
 * <br/>
 * Note the <b>{@literal @}Primary</b> annotation which tells Spring boot to
 * create this entity manager as the first thing when starting the application.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Primary
@Bean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    // Set the master data source
    em.setDataSource(masterDataSource());

    // The master tenant entity and repository need to be scanned
    em.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[] { Tenant.class.getPackage().getName(), ITenant.class.getPackage().getName() });
    // Setting a name for the persistence unit as Spring sets it as
    // 'default' if not defined
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("masterdb-persistence-unit");

    // Setting Hibernate as the JPA provider
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    // Set the hibernate properties
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return em;
}

/**
 * This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single
 * JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access. <br/>
 * <br/>
 * Note the <b>{@literal @}Qualifier</b> annotation to ensure that the
 * <tt>masterEntityManagerFactory</tt> is used for setting up the transaction
 * manager.
 * 
 * @param emf
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
public JpaTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("masterEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

/**
 * Bean post-processor that automatically applies persistence exception
 * translation to any bean marked with Spring's @Repository annotation, adding a
 * corresponding PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor to the exposed proxy
 * (either an existing AOP proxy or a newly generated proxy that implements all
 * of the target's interfaces).
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

/**
 * The properties for configuring the JPA provider Hibernate.
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.NON_CONTEXTUAL_LOB_CREATION, true);

    return properties;
}
```

Application.yml

```html
spring:
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true 
    generate-ddl: false
    jdbc:
        lob:
          non_contextual_creation: true
    hibernate: 
      ddl-auto: update
      use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false  
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        type: trace 
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false
      fail-on-self-references: false
      fail-on-unwrapped-type-identifiers: false
      
    visibility:
      field: any
    default-property-inclusion: non-empty
  application:
    name: '@pom.artifactId@'
    version: '@pom.version@'
    
              
multitenancy: 
  mtapp: 
    master: 
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://*******/masterdb
        username: *****
        password: *****
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        connectionTimeout: 20000
        maxPoolSize: 262143
        idleTimeout: 300000
        minIdle: 1
        poolName: dbtest-connection-pool
```

**Tenant**

```
public class TenantDatabaseConfig implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

@Bean(name = "tenantJpaVendorAdapter")
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager")
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("tenantEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
    return transactionManager;
}

/**
 * The multi tenant connection provider
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
    // Autowires the multi connection provider
    return crearDataSource();

}

@Bean(name = "datasource")
public DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl crearDataSource() {

    return new DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();

}

/**
 * The current tenant identifier resolver
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
    return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
}

/**
 * Creates the entity manager factory bean which is required to access the JPA
 * functionalities provided by the JPA persistence provider, i.e. Hibernate in
 * this case.
 * 
 * @param connectionProvider
 * @param tenantResolver
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider") MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
        @Qualifier("currentTenantIdentifierResolver") CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {

    System.out.println(" LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean PASO");
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    // All tenant related entities, repositories and service classes must be scanned
    emfBean.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[] { Empresa.class.getPackage().getName(), IEmpresa.class.getPackage().getName() });
    emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("tenantdb-persistence-unit");
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
    // ImprovedNamingStrategy is deprecated and unsupported in Hibernate 5
    // properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
    // "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"); // LUISINA
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, true);
    // properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION, true);

    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "validate");
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.NON_CONTEXTUAL_LOB_CREATION, true);

    emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return emfBean;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider;

@Override
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
}
```

}

Please, if anyone could help me. I am quite new to springboot.

Thank you.

Comment: maxPoolSize: 262143. This is way above 100 allowed in the db

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.Could you tell me what is the right value of should I go? Previously I had it in these values, maxPoolSize: 10 and  minIdle: 10 , but it also failed me and I saw in a forum they recommended me to place them like this. Thanks @Lesiak

Comment: There is no single good number, it depends on the load, average connection time etc. You need to start with a sensible number, and monitor numbervof concurrent connections, number of threads waiting for a connection, connection lease time etc and adjust your settings. There are some pools that try to do this automatically, like FlexyPool, but I never used it in practice. As a side note: you seem to configure a lot of services that are auto-configured in springBoot.

Comment: @Lesiak Many thanks. Your comment helps a lot. Really many settings were added by this theme. I should start cleaning a little. Thank you. A lot of help.